Variant of Birkhoff Orthogonality, Linear Analysis 4.12

I've tried using Riesz's Lemma and the reverse triangle inequality to show this, but I kept running into useless equivalencies.
Edit: I've managed to prove this weaker statement:
$$
\|y\|\le (1+\epsilon)\|x+2y\|
$$
I don't know how helpful this is.
I did as follows:
\begin{align*}
\|y\| &= \|\tfrac{1}{2}(1+\epsilon)(x+2y) - \tfrac12x - \tfrac{\epsilon}2(x+2y)\|\\
&\le \tfrac12(1+\epsilon)\|x+2y\| + \tfrac12\|x\| + \tfrac{\epsilon}2\|x+2y\|\\
&=\tfrac12(1+\epsilon)\|x+2y\| + \tfrac12\|x+y\| + \tfrac{\epsilon}2\|x+2y\| = (1+\epsilon)\|x+2y\|
\end{align*}

I found this solution for a slightly more general, but equivalent, problem in Classical Banach Spaces by Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri, which is due to S. Mazur.
Since $Y$ is finite dimensional, $S(Y)$ is compact. Thus, there exists a sequence $(y_i)_i^m \subset S(Y)$ such that $\forall y \in S(Y)$, $\exists i$ such that $\|y - y_i\| < \frac{\epsilon}2$.
Let $y_i^\ast \in X^\ast$ be given by $y_i^\ast(\lambda y_i) = \lambda$, and for $x\not\in \mathrm{lin}(y_i)$, $y_i^\ast(x) = 0$. Clearly, $\|y_i^\ast\| = 1$.
Since $Y$ is finite dimensional, there exists $x \in X \setminus Y$ such that, for all $i$, $y_i^\ast(x) = 0$. Letting $y\in S(Y)$, we have the following:
\begin{align*}
\|y + \lambda x\| &\ge |\|y_i - \lambda x\| - \|y - y_i\|| \ge \|y_i - \lambda x\| - \|y - y_i\|\\
&\ge \|y_i - \lambda x\| - \frac{\epsilon}2 \ge |y_i^\ast(y_i - \lambda x)| - \frac{\epsilon}2 = 1 - \frac{\epsilon}2 \ge \frac1{1+\epsilon} = \frac{\|y\|}{1+\epsilon}
\end{align*}
Where the last three statements follow if $0 < \epsilon < 1$. The case for $\epsilon \ge 1$ is as follows:
$$
\| y \| \le \|x + y\| + \|x\| \le 2\|x+y\|
$$
Where $x\in S(X)$, and this is guaranteed by Riesz's Lemma.
For $\|y\|\neq 1$, we let $\lambda' = \frac{\lambda}{\|y\|}$ and $y' = \frac{y}{\|y\|}$. This gives us the following:
$$
\|y'\| \le (1+\epsilon)\| y' + \lambda' x\| \iff \|y\| \le (1+\epsilon)\|y + \lambda x\|
$$
Which finishes the proof.
